# Loop not called always but function to check on change event called always inside the loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript, I have a question that little bit strange for me...

I have created checkboxes in HTML and I want to detect when checkbox checked, so in the function below, 
when I open the browser the loop below is called one time but when I check any time the checkBox the method of **`checkbox.onchange = function(e)`** is called always but the loop does not call any more, in general I think in programming when there is a method inside the loop, first loop called then method.

`checkbox.onchange = function(e)` so in this case I think before call this method program should call before loop then the method as the method inside the loop but my question is, why the method called without loop?

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check-completed')
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){

        const checckbox = checkboxes[i];

        console.log('list of checkbox ',checckbox);

        checckbox.onchange = function(e){
            console.log('event', e);               
        }

    }
```

Comment: `checkboxes[I]` Did you mean `i`? `I` is never defined

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake yes I mean i. I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check-completed')
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){

    const checckbox = checkboxes[i];

    console.log('list of checkbox ',checckbox);

    checckbox.onchange = function(e){
        console.log('event', e);


    }

}
```

when the page loads for the first time browser detects all actions and creates an event for each button or checkbox.
and the loop will work only once while loading

Comment: Thanks EveryOne for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is:

1. You are looping across all checkboxes
2. Picking individual checkbox
3. Attaching a event listener on each checkbox.
4. Thats it. Loop work is over. Loop will never execute again.

Now when you click on the checkbox it just calls the attached event handler. Now if you want to run the loop again, you need to add a for loop inside the event handler.

Something like this.

```
checckbox.onchange = function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkboxes[i].value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the loop will run only once, because javascript execute code from top to bottom and never the synchronous code more then once.

And on the other hand onchange is an event, javascript registered it as a listener and listen to the changes of the element and run the code on all changes.

Browser will create an event listener on the checkbox and listen to the changes and execute the function.

You can read more about events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)